# How to prevent Google Favicon bot to call to my site?

Tags: googlebot

I have some backend url that I use for myself in google chrome only. It's not open public. However for some reason, this bot "Google Favicon" ip located at Google call this URL which I do not want. My guess is Google get this URL from my Google Chrome and try to update cache to this URL everyday. What should I do? I'm not sure if I block its ip, there will be called from new ip later or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my problem in nginx, add this below to block by user agent. This solved my issue:

if ($http_user_agent ~* Google\ Favicon ) {
    return 403;
}